# String displayed but undefined in my console and condition?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, auth0

I have a problem, i wan't to compare two id, but i have an issue with variables, i can display this string but when i compare it and i tried print it in the console it return undefined ?

```
export default function all_Cards(widget, user_id) {
    const i = widget.widget_id;
    console.log('widget.user_id', widget.user_id, 'user_id', user_id); // here user_id is undefined
    // if (widget.user_id == "auth0|6193bba9ab79c900713a1a26") {
    return (
      <div className={styles.card} key={i} data-grid={{x: widget.x, y: widget.y, w: widget.w, h: widget.h, isResizable: false}}>
        <div className={styles.card1}>
        <div class={styles.container_c}>
          <img src="/newyork.jpg" alt="las vegas"/>
          </div>
            <div class={styles.details}>
              <h3>{user_id}</h3>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Praesentium dignissimos, minus aperiam adipisci exercitationem.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        {/* <span className={styles.card_delete} onClick={this.onRemoveItem.bind(this, i)} ></span> */}
      </div>
    );
    // }
}
```

That's the code, call the upper fonction,

```
const ResponsiveReactGridLayout = WidthProvider(Responsive);

export default class AddRemoveLayout extends React.PureComponent {  
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.widgets = props.widgets;
    this.user_id = props.user_id;
    this.onBreakpointChange = this.onBreakpointChange.bind(this);
    this.AllCards = AllCards.bind(this)
  }

...

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ResponsiveReactGridLayout
          onLayoutChange={this.onCustomLayoutChange}
          onBreakpointChange={this.onBreakpointChange}
          {...this.props}
        > 
          {this.widgets?.map((widget) =>
            this.AllCards(widget, this.user_id)
          )}
        </ResponsiveReactGridLayout>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The props.user_id is the useUser of auth0 package auth.

```
export default function Body_m(props){
  const {user} = useUser();
  const widgets = props.widgets;
  const user_id = user?.sub;
  return (
    <main>
      <AddRemoveLayout widgets= {widgets} user_id= {user_id}/>
    </main>
  )
}
```

Comment: Your code isn't clear. if it's react-function-component the function name must be like `AllCards`. Please add more example and information about your probleme

Comment: I update it, this is my first post sry, thx for the reply

Comment: As @Melvynx mentioned, `all_Cards` is a React function component so you should use it as such. Change its signature to `AllCards({ widget, user_id })` then in `AddRemoveLayout` use it directly (no need to bind it) as `<AllCards widget={widget} user_id={this.user_id} />`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `else{}` to your code

```
if (widget.user_id == "auth0|6193bba9ab79c900713a1a26") {
   return(
   //code you have typed inside already 
   )
 
}
else{
   return (
      <div>Loading</div>
   )
}
```